# Whats the correct way to implement queue of associative array in systemverilog?

Tags: system-verilog

I have declared a unbounded queue of 2-D associative array as below :

```
 static bit [15:0] array[4][*][$];
```

I intend to access the array using bit vector, as follows :

```
array[0][4'b{info[31:28]}].push_back(info[18:6]);
```

I get the below compile error :

```
** Error: (vlog-13057) driver.sv(95): Expecting numeric digits.
```

Whats wrong here ?

Comment: what is this `4'b{info[31:28]}` supposed to mean? Just `info[31:28]` should be sufficient.

Comment: I thought explicit typecast was needed, i was wrong, it works when i remove the 4'b

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to write `4'(info[31:28])` as a cast to 4 bits, but there is no need to do that as `info[31:28]` is already 4 bits.

Also, do not use the wildcard `[*]` index in your declaration. It prevents you from using other features you might want to use later, like `foreach` loops and `find` array methods. Use `[bit [3:0]]` instead.